Weather seal wood windows
Wood frame windows are from the late 90’s.  A few windows have what appears to be a very thin piece of foam glued to the window frame but most are deteriorating. Are any of these slots what I would use for a kerf style weatherstripping or is there another type I should use? ]1

I take it from your description that other windows of the same type either had a kerf seal, nothing or the seal was applied to the frame instead of the sash.
If you can find low profile kerf mounted bulb seal(s) (it looks like you also have a kerf near the outside of the sash as well), that would be the first choice. The second choice would be to install an adhesive backed bulb seal(s) to the frame in the corners.
